# How to write a simple Node.js App that taks dump output to browser?

Tags: node.js, rest, web, socket.io

I familiar to Node.js and just a little bit about web programming. One of my CLI Node app need to let user see the running program logs. I hope she can open a separated browser and point to something like `http://localhost:12345`, then she got live log keeping scrolling in the page without any human interaction.

Is that a simple method to do such kind of application? I know programming RESTful, not sure if it helps.

Comment: Please paste what you have tried, lookup `expressjs` and `socket.io` for for more information. refer [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to show live server side logs to the user. For that you will have to tail the log file and pipe the output to response or pipe the stdout (if you're not writing logs to file) to the response using socket.io connection. socket.io is a way of providing live updates to the users without them sending https request every time. You can see example [here](https://medium.com/@noufel.gouirhate/build-a-simple-chat-app-with-node-js-and-socket-io-ea716c093088) .

Comment: Thanks @Yogeshwar socket.io looks very good.  For this simple requirement, how many code I need to add assuming client and server side are all JS.

Comment: check this github repo https://github.com/kilianc/rtail I think this has the complete solution for your problem.